# Converting a list back to a map of maps

Tags: clojure

I have a function that returns a struct that has two fields, :key :event. The :event field is a map (decomposed Java object retrieved from a cache). In the REPL, I see the return value as a map.

I then apply, `(def events (map #(make-event %) (keys events-cache)))`, applying the make-event function for each key from the cache, and want a map back containing each event map keyed by key.

What I get back is that, but inside a list. So calling any map functions, to search etc., throws an error, *clojure.lang.LazySeq cannot be cast to clojure.lang.IFn*.

I'm sure I'm thinking about this all wrong, but is there a way to pull the map of maps from the list?

Comment: It's a bit hard to visualize the data you mean here - it would help to have a [possibly simplified] example of what `events-cache` looks like, and what `make-event` does. It looks right now like the values from `events-cache` never get used in the output of `events`.

Comment: user> (keys events-cache)
(44 29 76 36 26 33 65 25) For each key I call make-event. make-event returns a clojure map. What I want is a map of these maps, but I get a list contains a map of maps.

Comment: user>events
({:key 44, :event {:name "S-test#1", :status "Opened", :start #<Date Tue Jun 15 13:27:00 EDT 2010>, :tv "", :sport "Soccer", :home "Manchester United FC", :away "Liverpool FC"}} {:key 29, :event {:name "Singles Woods v Harrington", :status "Opened", :start #<Date Thu Mar 11 00:00:00 EST 2010>, :tv "Sky Sports", :sport "Golf", :home "Tiger Woods", :away "Padraig Harrington"}}). Is this because the map function returns a list?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Maybe this is what you want?

```
(into {} (for [k (keys events-cache)]
           [k (make-event k)]))
```

Comment: Perfect. Thank you. Actually this answers a few more questions for me also.

Answer (score 1):

Your terms are vague, and the error message you post suggests the issue is of a very different sort than the question you're asking. You're likely to get more help if you post some code, and *especially* a real stacktrace.

But in general, this error message says "You have a lazy seq object that you are trying to call as a function", like:

```
(let [m1 (map some-function whatever)
      m2 (...more stuff...)]
  (m1 m2))
```

If you want to *return* a two-element list of `m1` and `m2`, rather than *calling* `m1` as a function with `m2` as an argument, you want to use the `list` function:

```
(list m1 m2)
```

Comment: I'm expecting a map of maps, so that I can search using (events 42) and get the map with key 42 and the value. I understand the error, as I don't have a map.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you don't care about whatever the values of `events-cache` were, and that you want to end up with a map of the `events-cache` keys to the things you generate with `make-event`, you could do:

```
(def events
  (let [event-keys (keys events-cache)]
    (zipmap event-keys (map make-event event-keys))))
```

I'm not sure why you'd have a cache that includes values, but then not use those values, but that's another question :)

Comment: The cache (Java Map) has an Integer key and a Java object as a value.I just want to pull the properties that I need from the object, and have a Clojure map with the key, and my map of required properties. Sorry the question is a bit vague.

Answer (score 1):

And just for fun:

```
(into {} (map (juxt identity make-event) event-keys))
```

Comment: Indeed fun. +1 for a use of juxt with identity. Where did you get the inspiration for that?

Comment: Dunno. I don't remember whether I read it somewhere, or whether I came up with it myself. I found this idiom nice.